# Puppeteer: Can't access iframe elements after update from 2.1 to 3.1 with built-in firefox

Tags: google-maps, firefox, iframe, puppeteer

I recently updated my puppeteer version from 2.1 to 3.1. I was using pupeteer-firefox on the previous version. And now since pupeteer 3.1 has firefox built-in, I am using that. But it's only an experimental feature from pupeteer.

This code was working properly with the previous version.

```
        const elementHandle = await page.$("iframe[src^=\"https://docs.google.com/picker\"] [id=\":7\"]")
        await elementHandle.click()
```

**Steps to reproduce**

- login to google: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&gl=en
- Go to: https://www.google.com/maps/d/?hl=en&gl=en
- Create a new map
- search for a location and add it to the map
- click on the add image icon [image icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5Pxi.png)

Now an iframe will open up. I need to click on the element with `id=":7"` inside the iframe and input image url. Can some one please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the official test result of puppeteer's firefox.

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/remote/puppeteer-expected.json

Every test against `iframe` is either `FAIL` or `SKIP`.

And google won't give support for firefox inside the pupeteer.

So I've come to the conclusion that it's not possible to access the `iframe` using pupetteer especially when cross-site scripting is banned.

I've abandoned puppeteer and started using microsoft's playwright. And everything's going good.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that not Google is working on Puppeteer support in Firefox. And as you already said yourself Firefox support is in experimental stage right now. That said we are working hard to add better support for various features and APIs, but that's not a task that can be done within a week.

In regards of your question I can say that I added iframe support for a lot of APIs recently, and it's all available in Firefox 79 now.

Also note that Playwright is using a modified and unofficial Firefox build based on a recent Firefox beta.